# Javascript page rendering as text instead of executing document.location

Tags: javascript

How can I get an external page (http://www.example.com/js_redirect.js) to execute as javascript instead of text? I have set the page header to application/javascript and the page source is

```
window.location.href='http://www.example.com/landing.html';
```

Going to that url just renders the page as text.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do.

Comment: If I were to go to the url http://www.example.com/js_redirect.js in my browser, I want the javascript on that page to execute so that it redirects me to http://www.example.com/landing.html. It doesn't. It just renders the javascript code as text.

Comment: @NickBoutelier Is my solution what you are looking for? If not let us know what is your need. If you don't care about users answer, no one will answer your future questions. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is the correct one. I was hoping it would be possible for the browser to parse a page as javascript by using the header info, but I guess they can only parse html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery's [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) instead of a script tag.

```
$.getScript("http://www.example.com/js_redirect.js");
```

or pure JavaScript

```
var scr = document.createElement("script");
scr.src = "http://www.example.com/js_redirect.js" + "?ts=" new Date().getTime();
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].append(scr);
```